# Bulk Upload not working for Polymodel in appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

Bulk upload for an Entity of type db.polymodel.PolyModel fails with the following error (I have managed to upload other Entities and all imports should be present):

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130901.191015
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/program files (x86)/google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 171, in
<module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "c:/program files (x86)/google/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 167, in
run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4252, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4243, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 2402, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3979, in __call__
    return method()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3791, in PerformUpload
    run_fn(args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3682, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 4395, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 4206, in _PerformBulkload
    LoadConfig(config_file)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 3873, in LoadConfig
    Loader.RegisterLoader(cls())
  File "SubscribLoader.py", line 23, in __init__
    ('description', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 2674, in __init__
    GetImplementationClass(kind)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 968, in GetImplementationClass
    implementation_class = db.class_for_kind(kind_or_class_key)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\_
_init__.py", line 296, in class_for_kind
    raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind)
google.appengine.ext.db.KindError: No implementation for kind 'DbSubscrib
```

'
Here is the command Line :

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=SubscribLoader.py --filename=Subscrib.csv --
kind=(DbProduct,DbSubscrib) --url=https://.../_ah/remote_api -A appname
```

Here is the Loader Class

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
from Db.shop.DbSubscrib import DbSubscrib


class SubscribLoader (bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, ('DbProduct','DbSubscrib'),
                                   [
                                    ('name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('createDate',
                                     lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date()),
                                    ('level', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('duration', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('service', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('description', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                   ])

loaders = [SubscribLoader]
```

DbSubcrib derives from DbProduct which drives from polymodel.PolyModel

Btw, I have tried to add another extra property 'class' which is hardcoded to DbSubscrib' (also tried to add 2 properties 'DbProduct' and 'DbSubscrib', without any luck.

Any help is much appreciated. I could not find a document on goole's site that goes into any nuances around PolyModel and bulkupload.

Comment: I use polymodel (both in ndb, and db) and there is no basic problem with PolyModel with bulk upload .  Are you using `upload_data` option - ie all data or a bulk config or uploading a specific kind, can you show your command line.

Comment: Added command line and uploader python. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your problem is you can't upload `DbSubScrib`, you need to us `DbProduct`.  If you look at any `DbSubScrib` as it is stored in the Datastore it is a `DbProduct` class, and the subclass will have an `class` attribute in the datastore of storing the inheritance class names

e.g

```
 class  value: ["DbProduct", "DbSubScrib"]
```

Chnage your loader class to DbProduct and it will work.

Comment: Yes, but it creates a DbProduct. How do I tell it to create a DbSubscrib. I have tried to provide that at the command line thru the --kind, then I tried to provide it loader.__init__ (self, "DbSubscrib".. and then I tried to add a 'class', lamda x: ['DbProduct','DbSubscrib'], .... None of these worked. Each time I get a different error. I am looking for a way to create a subclass of a PolyModel. Many thanks for your answer !

Comment: Thats correct behavioyr.  You need to understand how PolyModel works.  Everything that subclasses DbProduct is stored as DbProduct.  When you use DbSubscrib class to fetch things it will only fetch DbSubscrib entities ie with the class attribute that holds DbProduct and DbSubscrib.  Hvae a look at you entities in the datastore viewer then you will see what is going on.

Comment: I recognize the details of PolyModel behaviour including the point about fetch and how it works thru the extra 'class' attribute/etc.. What I am looking for is a way to bulk upload DbProduct entities that contain the right class attribue value and other DbSubscrib attributes. My .Subscrib.csv files has the extra attributes of the subclassed DbSubscrib entity. So essentially what do I need to do (command line argument or modifications to the Uploader python class above) so that it creates a DbProduct with the right class value and pushes the details of DbSubscrib attributes values from the .csv

Answer (score 0):

After a little tinkering, found the issue in google appengine's bulkuploader : it seems there was an attempt to make bulkupload work for PolyModel but not sure why this part was not fixed (or tested). Perhaps I am missing something - in anycase it works for me with these changes... The fix is in the following line of  google.appengine.tools.bulkloader.py :

```
class BulkTransporterApp(object):
  """Class to wrap bulk transport application functionality."""

  def __init__(self,

....
....


line 3399 - old -     self.kind = arg_dict['kind']

line 3399 - new -    self.kind = ParseKind (arg_dict['kind'])
```

After this change I was able to upload.

I have fixed the Bulkuploader module and command line above for how it should be to upload a PolyModel.